# add message after price to multiple categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a sting of code for woocommerce that adds "per square foot" after product price of a select category. I have added another category which I want "per square foot" to apply to as well. I think I need to add an array which i have tried without success. Here is what I have that works for the single category

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
 
function custom_price_message($price) {
 
if ( !has_term( 'stone', 'product_cat' ) ) {
   return $price;
    
} elseif (!empty($price)){
   $vat = ' per ft<sup>2</sup>';
   return $price . $vat;
    
 }else{
   return 'Call for Price';
 }
}
```

Comment: Basically, i need to know how to make an "if has term" function apply to more than one product category.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what I did wrong the first time but here but I figured out. Here is the array I used.

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
 
function custom_price_message($price) {
    
// Set HERE your product categories in the array
$categories = array( 'stone', 'remnants' );
 
if( !has_term( $categories, 'product_cat' ) ){
   return $price;
    
} elseif (!empty($price)){
   $vat = ' per ft<sup>2</sup>';
   return $price . $vat;
    
 }else{
   return 'Call for Price';
 }
}
```